# Each phrase end with dot

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex `/'(.*?)'/` who give me this result :

```
string(10) "employeeId"
string(38) "Identity codes are not configured yet."
string(18) "orghead_rep_manger" 
string(61) "Please select reporting manager to current organisation head."
```

I want to check the string that end with dot :

> Identity codes are not configured yet.
>
> Please select reporting manager to current organisation head.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<=")[^"]+?\.(?=")`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vPixb3/3)

Comment: Here is the result :

array(13) {
    [0]=>
    string(45) "Employee ID already exists. Please try again."
    [1]=>
    string(84) "FlashMessenger")->addMessage(array("success"=>"Organization head added successfully."
    [2]=>
    string(45) "Employee ID already exists. Please try again."


i want just :

Employee ID already exists. Please try again.
Organization head added successfully.
Employee ID already exists. Please try again.

Thanks

Comment: @KaderBendahmane, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\` escape for the period `.` character combined with the end of string token `$`.

```
/\.$/
```